# UDF (User Defined Function) python gives different answer in pig

Tags: python, apache-pig, jython, udf

I want to write a UDF python for pig, to read lines from the file called like

```
#'prefix.csv' 
spol.
LLC 
Oy
OOD
```

and match the names and if finds any matches, then replaces it with white space. here is my python code

```
def list_files2(name, f):
    fin = open(f, 'r')
    for line in fin:
        final = name
        extra = 'nothing'
        if (name != name.replace(line.strip(), ' ')):
            extra = line.strip()
            final = name.replace(line.strip(), ' ').strip()
            return final, extra,'insdie if'
    return final, extra, 'inside for'
```

Running this code in python,

```
>print list_files2('LLC nakisa', 'prefix.csv' )
>print list_files2('AG company', 'prefix.csv' )
```

returns

```
 ('nakisa', 'LLC', 'insdie if')
 ('AG company', 'nothing', 'inside for')
```

which is exactly what I need. But when I register this code as a UDF in apache pig for this sample list:

```
nakisa company LLC
three Oy 
AG Lans 
Test OOD
```

pig returns wrong answer on the third line:

```
((nakisa company,LLC,insdie if))
((three,Oy,insdie if))
((A G   L a n s,,insdie if))
((Test,OOD,insdie if))
```

The question is why UDF enters the if loop for the third entry which does not have any match in the prefix.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `pig` but the way you are checking for a match is strange and might be the cause of your problem.

If you want to check whether a string is a substring of another, `python` provides
the `find` method on strings:

```
if name.find(line.strip()) != -1:
    # find will return the first index of the substring or -1 if it was not found
    # ... do some stuff
```

additionally, your code might leave the file handle open. A way better approach to handle file operations is by using the `with` statement. This assures that in any case (except of interpreter crashes) the file handle will get closed.

```
with open(filename, "r") as file_:
    # Everything within this block can use the opened file.
```

Last but not least, `python` provides a module called `csv` with a `reader` and a `writer`, that handle the parsing of the csv file format.

Thus, you could try the following code and check if it returns the correct thing:

```
import csv

def list_files2(name, filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_:
        final = name
        extra = "nothing"
        for prefix in csv.reader(file_):
            if name.find(prefix) != -1:
                extra = prefix
                final = name.replace(prefix, " ")
                return final, extra, "inside if"
        return final, extra, "inside for"
```

Because your file is named `prefix.csv` I assume you want to do prefix substitution. In this case, you could use `startswith` instead of `find` for the check and replace the line `final = name.replace(prefix, " ")` with `final = " " + name[name.find(prefix):]`. This assures that only a prefix will be substituted with the space.

I hope, this helps

Comment: Hi, the command with open(filename, "r") as file_: can not be used in pig. It gives this error: Syntax error: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

Comment: I tried the code with name.find(prefix)!= -1 , python works but pig no!

Comment: Ok, which Version of `python` are you using locally? and which version does `pig` use? May this be the problem? Seems like your `pig` is using a VERRY old `python 2.5` or something like that

Comment: I use Python 2.7.6 but Pig uses Jython to execute Python UDFs, so they must be compatible with Python 2.5 and cannot use Python 3 features.

Comment: Okay, so this will most likely be the point, why your code is working in your `python 2.7` installation and not in `pig`s `jython`. Have you tried installing `jython` locally and run your code in it? Does it behave like in your `python 2.7`? Maybe you should add a jython tag to your question.